# Web scraping (Scrapy) through a REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

**This is the current setup:**

I have the code below which works with Scrapy and Selenium on my computer (except for some prices that are not loaded. I have to figure out how to handle dynamic loads)

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class product_spiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price=scrapy.Field()
    pass

class MyspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ['ebay.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=books&_osacat=0&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.Xpython&_nkw=python&_sacat=0&_from=R40']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        sel = scrapy.Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        for prod in sel.xpath('//ul[@id="GalleryViewInner"]/li/div'):
            item = product_spiderItem()
            item['title'] = prod.xpath('.//div[@class="gvtitle"]/h3/a/text()').extract()
            item['price'] = prod.xpath('.//div[@class="prc"]//span[@class=" bold"]/text()').extract()
            yield item

    def closed(self, reason):
        self.driver.close()
```

**Requirement:** I would like to use this functionality in my website. So, the ideal scenario is that users ask for data (e.g. click on button), our website sends an HTTP request to a REST API (probably on the Scrapy Cloud?), we start the Scrapy spider and return the result in JSON format which will be then shown to the users of our website. I came across [ScrapyRT](http://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

1- I had used it before locally by: `http://localhost:9080/crawl.json?spider_name=myspider&url=https://www.example.com` but in this case I get the following response:

```
{"status": "ok", "items": [], "spider_name": "myspider", "stats": {"downloader/request_bytes": 940, "downloader/request_count": 2, "downloader/request_method_count/GET": 2, "downloader/response_bytes": 20024, "downloader/response_count": 2, "downloader/response_status_count/200": 1, "downloader/response_status_count/302": 1, "finish_reason": "finished", "finish_time": "2017-06-25 13:45:16", "log_count/DEBUG": 10, "log_count/INFO": 8, "response_received_count": 1, "scheduler/dequeued": 2, "scheduler/dequeued/memory": 2, "scheduler/enqueued": 2, "scheduler/enqueued/memory": 2, "start_time": "2017-06-25 13:45:12"}, "items_dropped": []}
```

2- Even if I make it work locally, how can I host it on the Scrapy Cloud?

I don't need a solution specific to Selenium or ScrapyRT. Basically, anything that satisfies the above requirement is ideal.

Comment: I don't think scrapy cloud api allows this but you can start the job like you're doing right now and use another api call to check for job status and acquire items.

Comment: @Casper, thanks. Maybe, a better (simpler) question is how can I serve my Selenium-based service through a REST API? What are my options (let's forget about Scrapy and its Cloud server)

Comment: @towi_parallelism This is exactly the issue I had with scrapy spiders when trying to implement a REST API to start crawling them. Hence I implemented [this project](http://arachne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) so future scrapy enthusiast could build upon it.